# Install Windows 8.1 in UEFI mode with a flash drive

Tags: windows-8.1

Suppose the usb flash drive is formatted to FAT32 , we just simply copy all the Windows installation files to the usb flash drive( including \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI), is it possbile to install win 8.1 in UEFI mode with this flash drive, is the flash drive uefi-bootable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but what you're better off doing is either using [MDT2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40796) if you're in a corporate\enterprise environment or using the Microsoft [ISO to USB](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) tool.

Comment: yes ,I know there're many tools out there can acheive this goal, and there're many other ways to intall win 8.1. I just want to know what makes it possbile ,and what makes it impossbile.There a guide on how to make a flash drive uefi bootalbe, it uses "diskpart" to format the flash drive with following commands, list disk ,   select disk X, clean,create partition primary, format fs=fat32 quick, active, assign, list volume, exit. but I don't see how it's different from simply formatting the drive to FAT32 in windows? The flash drive is still MBR partition not GPT.

Comment: the link of the guide [link](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Creating_Windows_UEFI_Boot-Stick_in_Windows)